# How to implement autoscroll in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have datagridview that has 25 to 100 rows. I am performing a task in seperate thread .Each row depicts a single task. I am selecting the row on which task is performing, if suppose the row is 15 which is invisible then I want to move that row to the visible area.
It will autoscroll to the selected row..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx)

Comment: if you dynamically add to the table a lot of items this works very slooooow

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 15;
```

See the documentation of [`DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

This one scrolls to the selected row without put it on top.

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess if you select a row programatically, it will scroll to it.

or you can use `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` or `FirstDisplayedCell` member to make it first cell on the top left